# xslt shbang: Using xslt from the command line

Tags: scripting, executable, xml, shebang, interpreter

I have (foolishly?) written a couple of moderately general-purpose [xslt](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/)
 scripts.

I'd quite like to turn these into executables that read an xml document from standard in or similar.

The way you do this with other languages is to use a [shbang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Is there an easy / standard way to do this with xsltproc and friends? Sure I could hack up a wrapper around xsltproc that pulls off the first comment line... but if there is something approximating a standard this would be nicer to use.

Comment: Back in 2006: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/xslt/2006-January/msg00011.html

Comment: **The only right solution is to have OS support for what you want to do.** :)  There's something interesting about a programming language expecting the linux kernel to implement features so that their scripts can run...

Comment: that's essentially what binfmt is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the generic **binfmt-misc** kernel module that handles which interpreter is used when an executable file is run. It is typically used to allow you to run foreign architecture files without needing to prefix them with `qemu` or `wine`, but can be used to recognise any *magic* characters sequence in a file header, or even a given filename extension, like `*.xslt`.  See the kernel [documentation](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.6/source/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt).

As an example, if you have a file `demo.xslt` that starts with the characters

```
<xsl:stylesheet version=...
```

you can ask the module to recognise the string `<xsl:stylesheet` at offset 0 in the file and run `/usr/bin/xsltproc` by doing as root

```
colon=$(printf '\\x%02x' \':) # \x3a
echo ":myxsltscript:M::<xsl${colon}stylesheet::/usr/bin/xsltproc:" >/etc/binfmt.d/myxslt.conf 
cat /etc/binfmt.d/myxslt.conf >/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
```

You don't need to go via the `/etc` file unless you want the setting to be preserved over a reboot. If you don't have the `/proc` file, you will need to mount it first:

```
mount binfmt_misc -t binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
```

Now, if you `chmod +x demo.xslt` you can run `demo.xslt` with any args and it will run `xsltproc` with the filename `demo.xslt` provided as an extra first argument.

To undo the setup, use

```
echo -1 >/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/myxsltscript
```

Comment: This approach is ingenious. It's a shame that this approach doesn't deal well with initial comments and whitespace. I guess you really want to do stuff based on the extension.

Comment: Ah you can select the interpreter based on extensions... https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.rst . It's a bit magically and machine specific, but it does work.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change an XSLT stylesheet into an executable using a shebang.

Comment: Hmm... I have an ongoing concern about "that's impossible" answers. While you are  probably technically correct that a shebang is not valid xml that doesn't necessarily mean that there is a standard way achieving the effect that I was after. I could simply write my xslt scripts in a non-standard definition of xslt that allows hash bangs on the first line and use an interpreter that strips them.

Comment: @AttRigh. You certainly can try.   Please publish your work when you are done.  I would point out that "a non-standard definition of xslt" is not XSLT by definition.

Comment: "a non-stanard defintion is not" is not XSLT... well that's what non-standard means isn't it :P. But yeah. you end up with xslt files that can only be used as executables and can't be fed into other programmers, nevertheless this is the approach some other languages that don't support # comments use. Erlang being a good example.